# NVM and NodeJS support programs with standalone setup on Windows

Tags: node.js, nvm, nvm-windows

This might be an odd problem, but I find it troubling since [NVM](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows) is so much better solution than a standalone NodeJS installation which includes only one version of node.

Since NodeJS no longer requires Python 2.7 to build native modules on Windows, it has become increasingly hard to set up everything on a clean installation of Windows for projects that compile modules from source, unless we use installer from NodeJS site (NodeJS 14.20.0 has it), which includes all of that. For example node module [ttf2woff2](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows) is one of those special modules.

If I try to set up everything initially with [NVM](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows) those support programs are not installed and module compilation fails during installation.

Is there a way to download and install that bundle that includes all windows patches, compilers and the rest of support programs, without requiring me to install official NodeJS, and then just proceed to install all Node versions through [NVM](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows), which I use for my projects?